# java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\acct\accesscarddata (Access is denied)

Tags: java, exception, servlets, filenotfoundexception

I upload a file into server and read the file from server, when I open the folder in server I see the uploaded file but when I try to access the file to process it gives me the following exception :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\acct\accesscarddata (Access is denied)
```

Update :

code to upload file :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            InputStream is = request.getPart(part.getName()).getInputStream();
            int i = is.available();
            byte[] b = new byte[i];
            is.read(b);
            String fileName = getFileName(part);
            if(session.getAttribute("accesscardDatafileNname")!=null)
                session.setAttribute("accesscardDatafileNname", fileName);
            String uploadDir = getServletContext().getRealPath("/accesscarddata/");
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(uploadDir + "/"+ fileName);
            os.write(b);
            is.close();
        }
    }
```

this is how i call the method : `doGet(request, response);`

This is how I tried to read the file :

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    protected void readFile(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String fileName = "", employeeAttendanceFilePath = "";
        String _uploadDir = getServletContext().getRealPath("/accesscarddata/");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        if (session.getAttribute("accesscardDatafileNname") != null)
            fileName = (String) session.getAttribute("accesscardDatafileNname");

        employeeAttendanceFilePath = _uploadDir + "/" + fileName;
        List sheetData = new ArrayList();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(employeeAttendanceFilePath);
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);// gets the first sheet on workbook
            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
                // count=count+1;
                List data = new ArrayList();
                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                    data.add(cell);
                }
                sheetData.add(data);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }
        session.setAttribute("sheetData", sheetData);

    }
```

and the following is the stack trace :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\webapps\acct\accesscarddata (Access i
s denied)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
        at com.slingmedia.notifier.servlet.LeaveReportServlet.readFile(LeaveReportServlet.java:236)
        at com.slingmedia.notifier.servlet.LeaveReportServlet.doPost(LeaveReportServlet.java:159)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.j
ava:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999
)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.jav
a:565)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

It is the problem of access permission I suppose but don't know whether the same or some other problem.

Kindly provide me necessary inputs to solve this issue.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the folder `accesscarddata` instead of `accesscardDatafileNname`

```
if(session.getAttribute("accesscardDatafileNname")!=null)
            session.setAttribute("accesscardDatafileNname", fileName);
```

This will never set the attribute with the filename.

Comment: Although the answer Alexander gave you is a bit too short, he's correct. You are trying to read the directory and not the name of the file. The reason for this is (I assume) that the session variable you are using to store the filename is empty.

Comment: Yes, exactly same, but i set the file name in session but it is not getting set, also the method id being called thrice, dont know why. please see my update for uploading file.